# Overridden standard 'New' button is not getting displayed on Site

Tags: community, force.com-sites, site.com

Login through site, there was a 'New' button coming on recent listview for an object. I've overridden the standard button with VF page and enabled that VF page for the site but the 'New' button got disappeared.

Comment: Did you check the users permission for the page and the controller?

Comment: @Basti I've enabled the access for user profile. Is there anything which I'm missing specific with user permissions.

Comment: on permissions sets and profiles you have two sub categories: Apex Class Access and Visualforce Page Access. Make sure the page and the controller are both accessible for the user. whether through the profile or a perm set.

Comment: make sure the site guest user has the proper sharing access for the record

Comment: @RohitMourya the button was coming before overriding it with VF Page. I dont think its sharing access issue

Comment: @Basti Yes that access is given, but no luck!

Comment: If your community is Lightning Community, please check if you have enabled the checkbox for page to be used in Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

Standard action overrides are currently not supported in salesforce communities, as stated in this doc https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=5

That means that standard actions (such as View, New, Edit, and Delete) get disabled in the communities whenever you override them.

Our organisation extensively uses button-overrides to prepopulate the new records: that affects our communities by making the action buttons not available. That is strange since I don't see a technical reason for this limitation - the action overrides work just fine in both classic and lightning experience.

I understand there are some workarounds (such as creating quick actions or custom buttons), however that is not satisfactory from a maintenance perspective and from the community user experience. Please enable and support the overrides!
Please check:https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X17QAE

Answer (score 0):

When a New button is overridden through VF page, Setting for Visualforce page `Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages` should be set in order to display `New Button` on Salesforce 1 and Lightning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've enabled this but this is not helping too

Comment: What about community?